# Runas python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, runas

I use the code I find all over stackoverflow to run a `runas` program in Python:

```py
import subprocess as sp

prog = sp.Popen(
    ['runas', '/user:"user@domain.com"', '/netonly', '"C:\foo\bar.bat"'], stdin=sp.PIPE
)
ww = "p@ssw0rd".encode("utf-8")
prog.stdin.write(ww)
prog.communicate()
```

Some remarks before the problem:

- it is not unsafe, in production I can safe the password in a Key Vault and retrieve it when used
- we cannot change the authorization method, we have to connect with some external AD for... reasons

In cmd, the `C:\foo\bar.bat` asks for password and then works fine:
[image]

However, with subprocess I keep getting:

```
Enter the password for "user@domain.com":
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to acquire user password
```

What am I doing wrong? I reckon it's a newline / return error or something?

Comment: You are never writing a newline.

Comment: I know, but that's the only way I can guess the error is shown before the pw writing?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You are basically typing the password but then never pressing Enter.

Comment: The same happens if I put `"p@ssw0rd".encode("utf-8") + b"\n" `. And if I put a breakpoint on the line prog.stdin.write(ww), the RUNAS ERROR is shown even before the password is entered. 

How do I change the processing order to: 1. start runas, let it ask for pw, 2. insert pw, 3. hit (virtual) return 4. run the bat?